# Get Non-primitive Variables from within a Cobegin - Chapel

Tags: chapel

I want to compute some information in parallel and use the result outside the `cobegin`.

To be more precise, my requirement is to retrieve a domain (and other non primitive types) like this

```
var a,b: domain(1,stridable=true);
cobegin{
  a = foo1();
  b = foo2();
}
foo3(a,b);
```

I am aware of `sync/single` types but the do not work for domains.

Note: 
Using `out` in the procedure parameters also doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make writing race conditions more explicit, variables used in parallel constructs are treated as though they were passed to a function with `blank` intent.  For most types, this means they can be read, but not written to.

To make the variables modifiable within the parallel statement, you can use a task intent clause to give them `ref` intent.

```
cobegin with (ref a, ref b) {
  a = foo1();
  b = foo2();
}
```

The legal task intents are `ref`, `in`, `const`, `const in` and `const ref`.  The `out` and `inout` intents are not supported as task intents because *each* task would copy a value out in an unspecified order, resulting in a race condition.

See the subsection "Task Intents" in the "Task Parallelism and Synchronization" section of the [Chapel language spec](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/_downloads/chapelLanguageSpec.pdf) for more details.